# nifi routeOnAttribute filter expression modification through java

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm trying to extend routeOnAttribute class present in nifi, but as of my requirement I need to change the filter expression coming from nifi UI through my custom processor to a nifi compliant syntax and then pass it to nifi routeOnAttribute class.

But routeOnAttribute class does not expose any public method to set the filter expression.

So how am I supposed to set the filtering expression in routeOnAttribute class through java API?

Comment: why do you need to change the expression? do you want to create a new custom processor based on `routeOnAttribute`  or maybe you want to do this `change expression` just once before nifi start?

Comment: "do you want to create a new custom processor based on routeOnAttribute" -- yes I want to create a custom processor by extending the routeOnAttribute class. My custom processor would take an expression and enrich it and then should pass it on to  routeOnAttribute.onTrigger method.

Comment: as for me, the easiest way is to make a copy of [RouteOnAttribute processor](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/standard/RouteOnAttribute.java). I don't see a good way to extend it.

Comment: I also agree that copying and pasting RouteOnAttribute is likely the best way to extend it. I'd still like to understand why you need to do this though, what are you trying to do to the expression that can't be done in other ways through standard processors?

Comment: There are no standard producers that would help my cause. That is the reason I started writing a custom processor. But to conclude the class design of routeOnAttribute class does not support extending it in a efficient manner.